# Argument must be rect style object

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

This is part of my code that is not working properly, I have tried to set keys to make the paddle move up and down but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
playerOnePosition = (WINDOWHEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2

y = 0
moveY = 0

#Creates Rectangles for ball and paddles.
paddle1 = pygame.Rect(PADDLEOFFSET,(playerOnePosition,(y)), LINETHICKNESS,PADDLESIZE)

drawPaddle(paddle2)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True: #main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        # mouse movement commands
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                moveY = -5
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                moveY = 5
        if (event.type == pygame.UP):
            if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                moveY = 0
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                moveY = 0
    y += moveY

    clock.tick(50)
```

The error is:

> **Argument must be rect style object**

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Adalee I am new here, I already did right?

Comment: @Joaqin If I copy your code it fails to run because of imports and declarations of variables. Because we can't know for sure what your variables contain (eg `LINETHICKNESS`), we can't tell you what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Also, you define `paddle1` but use `drawPaddle(paddle2)` ... so what is `paddle2`?

Answer (score 0):

The line that does not work is this one:

```
paddle1 = pygame.Rect(PADDLEOFFSET,(playerOnePosition, (y)), LINETHICKNESS,PADDLESIZE)
```

[`Rect` expects four (or two, or one) parameters:](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

> *class* **pygame.Rect**
>   *pygame object for storing rectangular coordinates*
>   `Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect`
>   `Rect((left, top), (width, height)) -> Rect`
>   `Rect(object) -> Rect`

So you have `PADDLEOFFSET` of `left`, `LINETHICKNESS` for `width`, `PADDLESIZE` for `height`.

But for `top` you have `(playerOnePosition, (y))`, which is a tuple, not an integer as `Rect` expects. Change that to an integer and it will work.

`Argument must be rect style object` is a generic error message the `Rect` class raises when the parameters are of the wrong type.